# Facebook app - permissions varying from tester to tester

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Bit of an odd one: I've created an app that uses a jQuery AJAX request to query the Graph API and access a list of a given user's Likes (someone on my Friends list). I can use this within my app, and I get the same result as if I'd run the query through the Developer tools Graph API Explorer site (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).

The fun begins when people on the Testers list for the app (which is sandboxed) perform exactly the same actions, with the same friend (who isn't on the testers list); they don't receive any data back from the Graph API at all.

The testers have granted my app all the same permissions as I have, so why would we be getting different results?

Comment: I don't know the answer exactly, but I can tell you that only administrators and developer roles have all the rights to do everything you want in sandbox mode. Testers don't have the rights - this appears especially when you work with facebook collection and actions. Maybe you stuck here in same problems like others do with tester accounts in sandbox mode. Solution unknown.

Comment: After a lot of testing, I think I've found the cause: I've accessed the Graph API via the developer tools site, and have granted the Graph API separate permissions (that match the ones my app is requesting). The testers haven't, and they're not getting any data back from the Graph API.

This is very annoying, and I don't know how to fix it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally - I think I've found the solution.

By switching the Facebook JavaScript SDK file to a direct link rather than an asynchronous download, and calling the `FB.login` function with extra permissions defined in the `scope` later down the page:

```
FB.login(function (response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        // init app here
    } else {
        // cancelled
    }
}, { scope: 'user_likes,friends_likes' });
```

... the testers are able to access their friends' Likes. Phew!